# React.js: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Quiero agregar la funcion addOrRemoveFromFavs al element dentro del Route listado, pero me muestra el error del titulo (Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.) Cual sería la forma correcta de integrar esta función? debajo está el código del componente App y el componente listado

```
function App() {
  
  const addOrRemoveFromFavs = e => {
    console.log('OK FUNCIONA')
  }
  
  return (
  <>
    <Header/>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Login/>}/>
      <Route exact path='/listado' element={ (props) => <Listado addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} {...props} />}/>
      <Route exact path="/detalle" element={<Detalle/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/contacto" element={<Contacto/>} />
      <Route exact path="/resultados" element={<Resultados/>}/>
    </Routes>
    <Footer/>
  </>
  );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi componente listado, donde estoy haciendo render del contenido de una api, con una llamada hecha con axios

```
export default function Listado(props) {
  //esto levanta el token de localStorage

  let token = localStorage.getItem('item')

  console.log(props);


  const [ moviesList, setMoviesList ] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const endPoint = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=8508114bd8b2b74ec94d71e041f90d89&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate'
    //llamado con axios
    axios.get(endPoint)
      .then(response => {
        const apiData = response.data;
        console.log(apiData.results)
        //guardamos la info obtenida de la api en un estado, con el hook useState, lo que hace es que devuelve dos cosas: el valor del estado y una funcion que permite modificar el estado
        //el array va contener la info de apiData
        setMoviesList(apiData.results)
      })
      //catch permite agarrar los errores, si es que los hay
      .catch(error => {
        swal(<h2>Hubo errores, intenta mas tarde</h2>);
        console.log(error)
      })
  }, [setMoviesList]);

  console.log(moviesList)

  return (
    <>
    {/* si el token es falso
    { !token && <Link to="/"/>} */}
    <div className='row'>
      {/* ESTRUCTURA BASE */}
      {
        moviesList.map((oneMovie, idx) => {
          return (
            <div className='col-4' key={idx}>
              <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${oneMovie.poster_path}`} />
                <button 
                onClick={props.addOrRemoveFromFavs}
                className='favourite-btn'>  </button>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{oneMovie.title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>
                    {oneMovie.overview.slice(0, 100)}...
                  </Card.Text>
                  <Button variant="dark"><Link to={`/detalle?movieID=${oneMovie.id}`}>Go somewhere</Link></Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card> 
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Al parecer estás retornando la función desde el componente. Tendrías que modificar la pregunta y agregar el código del componente `Listado` a ver qué hace ese componente con la función que le estás pasando para darte una respuesta.

Comment: gracias, agregué el componente Listado, donde estoy haciendo una llamada a una api con axios y renderizando el contenido en varias tarjetas

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el problema está en tu `Route` component. No puedes pasar una función como `element` de `Route`. Tendrás enviar sólamente el componente.

```js
<Route exact path='/listado' element={<Listado addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} /> }/>
```

Aunque yo preferiría:

```js
<Route exact path="/listado">
  <Listado addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} />
</Route>
```

Puedes [ver en la documentación](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route) los tipos de `Route` donde dice "Type Declaration" y corroborar que el parámetro `element` no acepta una función. Entonces no tiene sentido incluso que le estés pasando `props` a `Listado`.